# How to fix error " [vuex] expects string as the type, but found object" on Firebase err promise

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I use firebase and vuex for restart the password of a simple user, The actual code works but have these error.

"Error: [vuex] expects string as the type, but found object"

If i see in console log type of it say that is a string

--------my action ----------

```
restablecer({ dispatch }, payload) {
    console.log(typeof payload.emailRecover)
    firebase
      .auth()
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(payload.emailRecover)
      .then(() => {
        const newPayload = {
          emailRecover: payload.emailRecover,
          notify: payload.notify
        };
        dispatch(newPayload);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        payload.notify({
          time: 4000,
          title: "Error",
          text: err.message,
          iconPack: "feather",
          icon: "icon-alert-circle",
          color: "danger"
        });
      });
  },
```

-------- the method on my view ------------

```
restablecerContraseña() {
      const payload = {
        emailRecover: this.rMail,
        notify: this.$vs.notify
      };
      this.$store.dispatch("restablecer", payload);
    }
```

I just want to send buy dont have errors in my promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```js
dispatch(newPayload);
```

Dispatch should be passed two arguments. The first is a string referencing the action name, the second should be the payload.

e.g.

```js
dispatch('actionName', newPayload);
```

I don't know what action you're trying to call so I can't be more specific.